# Can a Pokemon get a status condition of the same type?

Tags: pokemon-series

I know the title might sound a little confusing, so let me give a couple of examples.

If a pokemon is a poison type, can it be poisoned? If a pokemon is a fire type, can it be burned? This also goes for the other types; electric > paralyzed, ice > frozen. And of course if I'm missing any others.

In my experience of playing the games, I don't recall a time this ever happened to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there are various rules concerning that the [bulbapedia has the full list](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Status_ailment#Non-volatile_status)

- poison types cannot be poisoned (like steel and the immunity ability)
- paralyzed is not electric specific (glare and stun spore causes paralysis as well) and all types can be paralyzed
- freeze can also happen on all types but ice types are immune to ice caused freeze (the only other moves which can freeze are tri-attack and secret power)

Comment: As of generation 6 (X & Y), [`Electric-type Pokémon are now immune to paralysis`](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Paralysis#Generation_VI).